# Why do I get "String or binary data would be truncated" as an error?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

I have a problem with this:

> String or binary data would be truncated

And this is my coding:

```
String savePath = @"C:\Users\Shen\Desktop\LenzOCR\LenzOCR\WindowsFormsApplication1\ImageFile\" + fileName;

inputImageBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageLocation);
inputImageBox.Image.Save(savePath);

String sqlData = "INSERT INTO CharacterOCR(ImageName, ImagePath, Character, CharacterDescription)    
            VALUES('"+fileName+"', '"+savePath+"', '"+typeName+"', '"+CharDesc+"')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlData, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <<<<<error indicates here
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Ah, SQL injection.

Comment: How have you defined the database?  Do any of the fields have a limited number of characters that you are exceeding?

Answer (score 8):

Look at the schema of your table and look at the max lengths. You're probably trying to insert something larger than the max length.

Comment: And you really should use parameterized SQL commands....SQL injection is a bitch...just look at HBGary

Comment: Look at all the fields in your insert statement, I'd bet the issue is with the imagePath field

Answer (score 2):

It's generally considered better coding practice to store the paths to where your images are in your database, while keeping your images stashed in the appropriate directory structure.

If you're set on inserting image data into a database, kindly let everyone know what version your database is.

**EDIT:**

Pull up your SQL Schema for the `ImagePath` column, and tell me how many characters you have it defined to accept.

Next, before you execute your SQL, call `Console.WriteLine(savePath.Length)`.

Is `savePath.Length` greater than your `ImagePath` column definition?

Comment: @yet  No part of this "answer" actually answers the question "Why do I get “String or binary data would be truncated” as an error?" This should be a comment IMO.

Comment: Oh! I see. He's changed his code a little. Before, it looked like he was trying to store an Image into his SQL. Now, he's gone in and fixed the formatting, and it is clear now that he **is** inserting a path.

Answer (score 2):

That just means that one of the values you're trying to cram into a column is too long for the data type you've defined for that column.

For example, trying to `INSERT` "Hello" to a column that's only a `VARCHAR(4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error, when the column length is different when compared with the table definition and storedprocedure parameter.
**Example:**

I have a table called
`Employee` 
with a column `Reason` 
and while declaring the table the column length for `Reason`is `varchar(100)`

and while writing a stored procedure for the `Employee` table i am declaring `Reason` parameter as `@Reason varchar(250)`.

In this situation you will be getting this error.
So make sure that the column length is unique.